# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

```
list1 = ["name1", "info1", 10]
list2 = ["name2", "info2", 30]
list3 = ["name3", "info3", 50]
MASTERLIST = [list1, list2, list3]


def printer(lst):
    print ("Available Lists:")
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        print (lst[x])[0]
```

This code is returning the "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error when I try and run

```
printer(MASTERLIST)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The mistake that you are making is that you are whitespacing print function call wrong, it should be `print(list[x])[0]` according to PEP8, and your mistake becomes more obvious. ;)

Comment: Though the error message is different, this is basically the same problem as [NoneType has no attribute 'something'](/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 21):

The `print()` function returns `None`. You are trying to index None. You can not, because `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Put the `[0]` inside the brackets. Now you're printing everything, and not just the first term.

Answer (score 14):

The `[0]` needs to be inside the `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `list` as a variable name for it shadows the builtin.

And there is no need to determine the length of the list. Just iterate over it.

```
def printer(data):
    for element in data:
        print(element[0])
```

Just an addendum: Looking at the contents of the inner lists I think they might be the wrong data structure. It looks like you want to use a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 2):

Point A: Don't use list as a variable name
Point B: You don't need the [0] just

```
print(list[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexing e.g. [0] should occour inside of the print...

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["name1", "info1", 10]
list2 = ["name2", "info2", 30]
list3 = ["name3", "info3", 50]

def printer(*lists):
    for _list in lists:
        for ele in _list:
            print(ele, end = ", ")
        print()

printer(list1, list2, list3)
```