# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cleaned-data

Im trying to receive data in json format in django restframework and utilize the data immediately but i realize i get error that 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' and i feel that i need to use cleaned_data but i dont know how to use cleaned_data in rest framework...here is my code:

```
@api_view(['GET', "POST"])
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':     
        name = request.data.get('name')
        email = request.data.get("email")
        amount = request.data.get("amount")
        phone = request.data.get("phone")

        return redirect(str(process_payment(name, email, amount, phone)))
    else:    
        responseData = {  
            "Homepage": "Payment"
        }
        return Response(responseData)
```

Here is my traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/williamdapper/Desktop/payment/electronics/views.py", line 21, in home
    return redirect(process_payment(name, email, amount, phone))
  File "/Users/williamdapper/Desktop/payment/electronics/views.py", line 55, in process_payment
    link=response['data']['link']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[11/Oct/2021 15:19:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 95799
```

[That is the image of the error im getting below][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkOwa.png

Comment: You should include the code for `process_payment`. Why are you converting that outcome using `str`? Have you checked whether one of the four variables is `None` before being passed to `process_payment`?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something?r=SearchResults&s=2|143.5901), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866657/nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable?r=SearchResults&s=5|107.1203), or other posts with "NoneTpye" is not subscriptable?

Comment: @Wouter when i included the code of `process_payment`, the error persisted...If i print the variables, im getting exactly what i inputed but still, it tells me that 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: @marcelh Ive checked the questions, ive checked djangorestframework docs still its not working

Comment: please add the complete error traceback

Comment: Can you paste the process_payment code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. I printed the response at the process payment to see the error message, so I got:

```json
{'status': 'error', 'message': 'Invalid authorization key', 'data': None}
```

I now remember that I altered my secret key in the morning, so I got it from my dashboard and made the necessary corrections and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

*Wrong answer: Just replace `request.data` to `request.POST`*

### Edited

I see your traceback and found that the problem is in line 55 of your `views.py` where you use `response['data']`. It is None!

Comment: When I tried this `name = request.POST.get(('name'))` and did `print(name)` to see if it firstly get the data, it returned None

Comment: Please check your sent request in your browser developer tools, network tab. Check and see what is your sent post data.

Comment: all im getting is this : POST http://localhost:8000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)....Im not getting any specific posted data

Comment: Check your request. 500 error is the response

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/j8Tcd3K.png]

Comment: Very good. Now you click on the network at the right top of page and find the 500 error request. I think it is the first request. Click on it and see the request tab.

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/Uw0pYe0.jpg]....this is all im getting

Comment: Ok, refresh page to see the request

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/RpKYzIP.png]